# How can you see what associated model triggered a callback in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose that `Student` `belongs_to :contact` and `Teacher` also `belongs_to :contact`. Suppose that `first_name` is in `Contact`, and `Student` and `Teacher` have a first name *through* the `Contact` and has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact`.

In an `after_commit` callback, if `first_name` changes, I want to see if it came from `Student` or from `Teacher`. I'm not sure how to do this though, or whether it's even possible. Inside of `Student`'s `after_commit`, `previous_changes` doesn't have `first_name`. It's only in `Contact`'s `after_commit` that it shows up. So inside of `Contact`'s `after_commit` I want to see if it originated from `Student` or from `Teacher`.

How can I do that? Is there something similar to [`destroyed_by_association`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-destroyed_by_association=)? When I search for "by_association" in the docs I don't see anything else, nor do I see anything else in [Active Record Autosave Association](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).

Note: It is possible for a `Contact` to have both a `Student` *and* a `Teacher`, so it isn't as simple as just saying that if the `Contact` doesn't have a `Student` it must have came from `Teacher`.

Comment: are you trying to avoid a `polymorphic` association? because that would be the way to solve it.

Comment: 1) It would be nice to avoid. Is there a way to do it without the polymorphic association. 2) Can you elaborate on how the polymorphic association would solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add corresponding associations to `Contact` they will be accessible in `after_commit` callback:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :teacher
  has_one :student

  after_commit do
    p teacher || student
  end
end
```

```
>> Teacher.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'teacher' })
...
# after_commit START
#<Teacher id: 1, contact_id: 1>
# after_commit END
=> #<Teacher:0x00007fd28056a9f0 id: 1, contact_id: 1>
```

One caveat is that if teacher is not present it will hit the database:

```
>> Student.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'student' });
 ...
# after_commit START
  Teacher Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."contact_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["contact_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<Student id: 1, contact_id: 2>
# after_commit END
=> #<Student:0x00007fd2837bd9c0 id: 1, contact_id: 2>
```

Switching to polymorphic relationship is also a solution:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :contact, as: :contactable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :contact, as: :contactable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end

# NOTE: to add plymorphic relationship add this to contact migration:
#       t.references :contactable, polymorphic: true
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true

  after_commit do
    p contactable
  end
end
```

```
>> Student.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'student' })
 ...
# after_commit START        
#<Student id: 1>            
# after_commit END          
=> #<Student:0x00007f4a85c0d1c8 id: 1>

>> Teacher.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'teacher' })
 ...
# after_commit START        
#<Teacher id: 1>            
# after_commit END          
=> #<Teacher:0x00007f4a884e2a08 id: 1>
```

**Update**

You have access to everything if you put the callback in `Student` and `Teacher`, regardless of the above setup.

Polymorphic:

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :contact, as: :contactable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact

  after_commit do
    p self
    p contact
    p contact.previous_changes
  end
end
```

```
>> Teacher.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'teacher' })
 ...
# after_commit START
#<Teacher id: 1>
#<Contact id: 1, name: "teacher", contactable_type: "Teacher", contactable_id: 1>
{"id"=>[nil, 1], "name"=>[nil, "teacher"], "contactable_type"=>[nil, "Teacher"], "contactable_id"=>[nil, 1]}
# after_commit END
=> #<Teacher:0x00007fbf1bdd2db8 id: 1>
```

Belongs_to:

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact

  after_commit do
    p self
    p contact
    p contact.previous_changes
  end
end
```

```
>> Teacher.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'teacher' })
   ...
# after_commit START        
#<Teacher id: 1, contact_id: 1>
#<Contact id: 1, name: "teacher">
{"id"=>[nil, 1], "name"=>[nil, "teacher"]}
# after_commit END          
=> #<Teacher:0x00007f9f2ce6a730 id: 1, contact_id: 1>
```

If you must have `after_commit` in `Contact` you have to explicitly tell `Contact` that update came from `Teacher` or `Student`:

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact

  # NOTE: before saving, let contact know it's about to be updated
  #       by Teacher.
  before_save do
    contact.updated_from = :teacher
  end
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  # NOTE: just a temporary attribute
  attr_accessor :updated_from

  after_commit do
    print 'Updated from: '
    p self.updated_from
  end
end
```

```
>> Teacher.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'teacher' })
 ...
# after_commit START
Updated from: :teacher      
# after_commit END
=> #<Teacher:0x00007fd6a40459c0 id: 1, contact_id: 1>
```

Or without `before_save` callback in Teacher:

```
>> Teacher.create(contact_attributes: { name: 'teacher', updated_from: 'teacher' })
 ...
Updated from: "teacher"
```

Or override `contact_attributes=` method:

```rb
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact

  def contact_attributes= attributes
    attributes[:updated_from] = :teacher
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: I see that changes to `Student` or `Teacher` will trigger `Contact`'s `after_commit`. However, the issue is that inside `Contact`'s `after_commit`, I want to see if it was triggered by `Student` or by `Teacher`. In the non-polymorphic example you gave you kinda were doing this by saying `teacher || student`. But it is possible for a `Contact` to have both a `Teacher` _and_ a `Student`, so that won't be able to tell us which one the change came from. Similarly, for the polymorphic example, it is not the case that `Contact` has just one `Contactable`. It has multiple.

Comment: @AdamZerner derp. I totaly missed that last part of the question. See the update.